# How to format 2nd and 3rd lines on the first line?

Tags: linux, vim, text, formatting

I am using `VIM`, and I want to format 2nd and 3rd lines.
I can do it by `:2,3left<number of spaces>`

```
 * @brief:     Hello world
 * Hello world hello world
 * Hello world hello world
```

How to do it easier to get something like this?

```
 * @brief:     Hello world
 *             Hello world hello world
 *             Hello world hello world
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this 
pres Esc+: then press v then press enter , select the second and third lines , press =
https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/help/vim/reformatting.html

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you want to do it programmatically, but by using visual block, you can create a "column" selection one line 2,3 just before the H, and then use <kbd>></kbd> to increase the indentation. If you want to move further, you can then use <kbd>.</kbd>.

```
* @brief:     Hello world
*XHello world hello world
* Hello world hello world
```

Assuming your cursor is on X

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

If you want to insert 2 spaces, use capital I after visual selection :

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: As I understand it, so we just insert tabs. Can we insert space for many lines like this?

Comment: @MaximGusev : I have added the strategy to insert spaces. Using capital I, you will insert before the visual selection.